FutureProvider is not used without using Consumer
I noticed that FutureProvider from Provider is not used if you don't use Consumer. Can somebody explain why ? Is there an alternative to go in a FutureProvider without a Consumer?
Proof:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

Future<int> test() async {
  debugPrint("loading...");
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  return 1;
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    FutureProvider(
      initialData: 0,
      create: (context) => test(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // first test start here:
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Consumer<int>(builder: (context, res, child) {
      return Text(res.toString());
    }))));

    /* second test start here:
    return const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('second test'))));
    */
  }
}


Short explanation: The function isn't called; don't use resources when your data isn't needed.
If you want it to always be called no matter if it's used or not you can set lazy to false. With changing that, it gets called when the Provider is created.
FutureProvider(
  lazy: false,
  initialData: 0,
  create: (context) => test(),
  child: const MyApp(),
),

